# How to format Woocommerce tags cloud?

Tags: woocommerce, tags, action

Im using following function to output Woocommerce tag cloud:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_product_loop_tags', 5 );

function woocommerce_product_loop_tags() {
    global $post, $product;

    echo  wc_get_product_tag_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">'  , '</span>' );
}
```

I would like to remove links from tags, comma between them and I need to add to each tag unique class selector.
Is it possible to do this? If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks you, but I dont want to use widget or shortcode. I need to hook action to `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item` as I have in my code above.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I done it by myself, any review is welcome.
Should I "escape" anything?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_product_loop_tags', 5 );

function woocommerce_product_loop_tags() {
    global $post, $product;
        if ( is_array (get_terms( 'product_tag' ))) {
           $tags = get_terms( 'product_tag' );
           echo '<span class="tag-cloud">';
           foreach($tags as $tag) {
              echo '<span rel="tag" class="tag-'.$tag->slug.'">'.$tag->name.'</span>';
           } 
           echo '</span>';
        } 
}
```